# Is there an Java equivalent for excel vlookup?

Tags: java, android, vlookup

I'm currently coding my first android app and I need to perform an equivalent of excel vlookup. I have a table that will never change and that the user won't see. The user may entre a value that is not exacly in the table in wich case the app should use the value equal or smaller and return its equivalent (i.e: 7 -> 110.3). I will then use the returned value in a formula.

```
.   A     B      
1   0    110.3
2   5    110.3
3   10   110.7
4   15   111.2
5   20   111.3
6   25   112.3
```

Comment: Are the values in Column A all factors of 5?

Comment: No, it goes from 0 to 90 by factors of 5 but the last value in the column A i 91.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `TreeMap` has methods to find higher or lower keys and entries. Can be used for example like this:

```
private static final TreeMap<Integer, Double> table = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>();
static {
    table.put(0,  110.3);
    table.put(5,  110.3);
    table.put(10, 110.7);
    table.put(15, 110.7);
    table.put(20, 111.2);
    table.put(25, 112.3);
}

private static double lookup(int value) {
    Entry<Integer, Double> floorEntry = table.floorEntry(value);
    if (floorEntry == null)
        return -1; // or throw sth
    return floorEntry.getValue();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(lookup(7));
}
```

> 110.3